# Setting global variable across files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I want to set the value of a global variable x in file p2.py. Then, this value is to be used in p1.py. However, the value of x is not getting changed in p1.py. I have tried using global keyword. 
Could anyone tell me what is wrong in this code:

**p2.py**

```
x=''
def set_vals():
   global x
   x='a'
```

**p1.py**

```
from p2 import *
set_vals()
global x 
print x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have imported `from p2 import *`, you get a copy of the x which is local to p1. This is not the exact same x as in p2... its now a local variable 'x' in p1 which is also pointing to the same object as the 'x' in p2.

The `p2.x` and the `x` in p are both references to the same entity immediately after `import p2`. However, when you run `set_vals()`, it only changes the value of `x` (repoints the pointer) inside the p2 module. The x inside the p1 module remains pointing to the old thing.

The set_vals function and its global x are still part of the p2 module, even though they have been imported into p1. Hence, they will affect the value of x in p2 only. This happens because functions remember the scope that they are created in (read about closures to learn more).

You can try this, which will do what we expect...

```
import p2
print p2.x
p2.set_vals()
print p2.x  # p2.x will change
```

What your code is equivalent to...

```
import p2
x = p2.x
set_vals = p2.set_vals
del p2

set_vals()   # changes p2.x
global x
print x     # this and p2.x are not same anymore
```

Its clear that the `x` in p1 is a separate variable that's initially pointing to the same object as the 'x' in p2. Changing the `p2.x` pointer is is not going to change what `x` in `p1` is pointing to. 'x' in p1 keeps pointing to the same thing as it initially was.

Comment: I think it is better to just use dependency injection. In general, global variables make it difficult to consistently share state across files